# Default implementation of protocol extension in Swift not working

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

I'm trying to add functionality to an `NSManagedObject` via a protocol. I added a default implementation which works fine, but as soon as I try to extend my subclass with the protocol it tells me that parts of it are not implemented, even though I added the default implementation.

Anyone having Ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

```
class Case: NSManagedObject {

}

protocol ObjectByIdFetchable {
    typealias T
    typealias I
    static var idName: String { get }
    static func entityName() -> String
    static func objectWithId(ids:[I], context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> [T]
}

extension ObjectByIdFetchable where T: NSManagedObject, I: AnyObject {

    static func objectWithId(ids:[I], context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> [T] {
       let r = NSFetchRequest(entityName: self.entityName())
       r.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K IN %@", idName, ids)

       return context.typedFetchRequest(r)
   }
}

extension Case: ObjectByIdFetchable {

   typealias T = Case
   typealias I = Int

   class var idName: String {
       return "id"
   }

   override class func entityName() -> String {
       return "Case"
   }
}
```

The error I get is `Type Case doesn't conform to protocol ObjectByIdFetchable`

Help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We'll use a more scaled-down example (below) to shed light on what goes wrong here. The key "error", however, is that `Case` cannot make use of the default implementation of `objectWithId()` for `... where T: NSManagedObject, I: AnyObject`; since type `Int` does not conform to the type constraint `AnyObject`. The latter is used to represent instances of *class* types, whereas `Int` is a *value*  type.

> `AnyObject` can represent an instance of any class type.
>
> `Any` can represent an instance of any type at all, including function types.

From the [Language Guide - Type casting](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html).

Subsequently, `Case` does not have access to any implementation of the blueprinted `objectWithId()` method, and does hence not conform to protocol `ObjectByIdFetchable`.

---

Default extension of `Foo` to `T`:s conforming to `Any` works, since `Int` conforms to `Any`:

```
protocol Foo {
    typealias T
    static func bar()
    static func baz()
}

extension Foo where T: Any {
    static func bar() { print ("bar") }
}

class Case : Foo {
    typealias T = Int

    class func baz() {
        print("baz")
    }
}
```

The same is, however, not true for extending `Foo` to `T`:s conforming to `AnyObject`, as `Int` does not conform to the class-type general `AnyObject`:

```
protocol Foo {
    typealias T
    static func bar()
    static func baz()
}

/* This will not be usable by Case below */
extension Foo where T: AnyObject {
    static func bar() { print ("bar") }
}

/* Hence, Case does not conform to Foo, as it contains no
   implementation for the blueprinted method bar()    */
class Case : Foo {
    typealias T = Int

    class func baz() {
        print("baz")
    }
}
```

---

*Edit addition*: note that if you change (as you've posted in you own answer)

```
typealias T = Int
```

into

```
typealias T = NSNumber
```

then naturally `Case` has access to the default implementation of `objectWithId()` for `... where T: NSManagedObject, I: AnyObject`, as `NSNumber` is  class type, which conforms to `AnyObject`.

---

Finally, note from the examples above that the keyword `override` is not needed for implementing methods blueprinted in a protocol (e.g., `entityName()` method in your example above). The extension of `Case` is an protocol extension (conforming to `ObjectByIdFetchable` by implementing blueprinted types and methods), and not really comparable to subclassing `Case` by a superclass (in which case you might want to override superclass methods).

Comment: That's right I came to the same conclusion, I replaces Int with NSNumber and it worked. The problem with Any is, that it doesn't conform to VArgType and thus I can't use it as argument for the predicate. Thanks for your great explanation!

Comment: @GeorgKitz Happy to help!

Comment: @GeorgKitz Could you, then, simply constrain your generic type to  where I: CVarArgType ?

Comment: @MacBellingrath I tried that, but it doesn't seem to work, I can quite use CVarArgType as constraint for the generic type. The compiler error is not really helping in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the problem. I thought it's the typealias T which is the reason for not compiling. That's actually not true, it's I which I said to AnyObject, the interesting thing is that Int is not AnyObject. I had to change Int to NSNumber